# How to connect frontend to backend docker containers

Tags: .net, angular, docker-compose

I use .net 5 for backend and angular 12 for frontend. And I have Cors for backend:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["FrontendEndpoints"].Split(',')).AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
```

My FrontendEndpoint

```
"FrontendEndpoints": "http://frontend:4200",
```

Well, in my frontend app I have endpoints

```
authEndpoint: "https://backend:44374",
apiEndpoint: "https://backend:44374/api/v1",
```

My docker-compose see below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  database:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password123!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - "1433:1433" 
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/opt/mssql/data/
  backend:
    image: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/MyApp.API/Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/dev_cert.pfx
    ports:
      - "45763:80"
      - "45764:443"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d/https/:/https
    depends_on:
      - database  
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

So when I try to use the backend I can open swagger (https://localhost:44374/swagger/index.html) and do request the database. Everything is working. But when I open me frontend app, I can't connect to the backend.
Please someone help me...

Comment: Can you please provide the CORS error you are getting ?

Comment: POST https: //backend/token?username=login&password=password net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Yeah that's not a CORS error. That error is the result of either an invalid or non existant endpoint you are trying to POST to. Check the url.

Comment: absolutely correct! Just I am very silly. I change endpoint to https//localhost:44374 and in Cors changed to http:localhost:4200 and my frontend app started to work

Answer (score 1):

endpoints in your frontend app is incorrect. try to request to backend in its open ports. im not familiar with .net and i dont know on what port you are running your application. but i guess you have to change your frontend endoints to:

```
authEndpoint: "http://backend:80",
apiEndpoint: "http://backend:80/api/v1",
```

or

```
authEndpoint: "https://backend:443",
apiEndpoint: "https://backend:443/api/v1",
```

for doing that you cat open tab network when you make a request in swagger and see url of the requests.